# Laravel CPanel - New Image to public folder not showing

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

I have uploaded my Laravel app to CPanel and it works completely fine. Then, I was making some changes to the Views by adding some new blade files. I also add new images to the public folder, where I put my previous images and it was working completely fine. But when I load the new page, the images are not showing, only the older image that I have uploaded before.

The HTML tag is the same as the already existing image but why it is not showing?
This is the HTML tag that I use in the blade:

```
<img src="{{ url('images/logo-cimahi.svg') }}"/>
```

I put the images in the public/images/ for the already existing images but the new images in the same path not showing.

Does my image broken or do I have to do something with PHP artisan command?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear all Laravel's cache, just run the following command:

```
$ php artisan optimize:clear
```

This will be an ouput:

```
Compiled views cleared!
Application cache cleared!
Route cache cleared!
Configuration cache cleared!
Compiled services and packages files removed!
Caches cleared successfully!
```

Comment: It is still not working, is there any PHP artisan command that may be helpful?

Comment: if you go to http://your-url.com/images/logo-cimahi.svg  do you see your image?

Comment: or try to user assets()                                                                                              `<img src="{{ asset('images/logo-cimahi.svg') }}" alt="tag">`

Comment: for the  your-url.com/images/logo-cimahi.svg it shows the image, but when I tried the other image file (png, jpg) it was not showing the image. I tried using assets() too

Comment: Sometimes Apache doesn't recognize media type for svg, so try adding in your .htaccess:

   
  `AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz`